# Inline arrow functions | Empty arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am new to ReactJS and have a question regarding usage of inline arrow functions and unable to understand this even after multiple hours of reading JavaScript ES6 arrow function with ReactJS.

```
const PersonInputs = ({ idx}) => {
 return (
       <div key={`name-${idx}`}>
      <input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick={() => removePerson(idx)}/>
       </div>
    );
};
```

This is my removePerson function defined in a seperate js file:

```
 const removePerson = (index) => {
        let updatedPersons = [...personState];
        var temp = updatedPersons[index];
         updatedPersons = updatedPersons.filter(person => person.name !== temp.name);
         setPersonState(updatedPersons);
    };

  const blankPerson = { name: '', age: '' };
    const [personState, setPersonState] = useState([
        { ...blankPerson },
    ]);
```

removePerson function requires index as argument, however when i provide as below i get  TypeError: temp is undefined.

```
const PersonInputs = ({ idx}) => {
 return (
       <div key={`name-${idx}`}>
      <input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick={(idx) => removePerson(idx)}/>
       </div>
    );
};
```

I am not able to understand why onClick={(idx) => removePerson(idx)} this causes error, but works with onClick={(idx) => removePerson(idx)}. Can someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An `input`'s `onClick` event does not pass an index to your handler. You want the handle to use the `idx` from the `PersonInputs` parameter, as a closure.

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` passes a synthetic event, not the index. Remove `idx` as the `onClick` param:

```
const PersonInputs = ({ idx}) => {
 return (
       <div key={`name-${idx}`}>
      <input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick={() => removePerson(idx)}/>
       </div>
    );
}
```

Since your function is getting React's synthetic event vs your index, it's tossing a type error as a result.